# Why my Second scanf() isn't working in C++

Tags: c

I tried to use a string instead of a char but the string works fine, I'm still confused why can't I use a char for the 2nd scanf

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    void main()
    {
        char customer_code, service;
        
    
        printf("\n\nConsumer Type: ");
        scanf("%c", &customer_code);
        
        printf("\nis this your first time using our services? [Y/N] ");
        scanf("%c", &service);
    }
```

Comment: The enter key in first input is being put in second input. Either take care of that or flush the standard input.

Comment: @Shiv: fflush(stdin) is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217/4177009).

Comment: Put a space before the `%c` like `scanf(" %c", &customer_code);`

Comment: The `scanf` leaves the newline character in the buffer. A similar question can help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   int main()
   {
    char customer_code, service;
    

    printf("\n\nConsumer Type: ");
    scanf("%c", &customer_code);
    getchar();
    printf("\nis this your first time using our services? [Y/N] ");
    scanf("%c", &service);
    }
```